# Is a RAW-only camera economically justified?

Tags: raw, jpeg, pricing, raw-vs-jpeg, in-camera-processing

Is a digital camera which could only take RAW images economically justified? considering that RAW files may need less in-camera processing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no justification for removing JPEG processing in digital cameras for the foreseeable future, there are plenty of reasons not to use jpeg but none to make it completely unavailable.

From a performance perspective the biggest bottleneck is writing the file to storage card(s) and mandating bigger files would yield no speed improvement at all.

Cost wise there's no benefit to removing jpeg format, the processing chip would need all the same capabilities, be the same size and use the same amount of power with or without jpeg.  In most raw formats the embedded thumbnail is jpeg which means the code to produce a jpeg would still be necessary anyway even if the user couldn't select it as the main output format.

Having such a ubiquitous format (even with its limitations) is considered useful enough that even medium format cameras have an option to output in JPEG (see [Pentax 645D specs](http://www.ricoh-imaging.co.uk/en/medium-format-digital/specifications/645D.html)) and if there was a user group who would be less interested in jpeg it would be MF users.

Answer (score 6):

Nope.

From a manufacturers point of view, it wouldn't even be a different camera. They'd sell the exact same camera with some firmware that prevented jpeg compression. When it comes to integrated circuits, mass production is where the money comes from. A product with reduced feature set is often just cannibalised with a special firmware. I remember how I was able to double the memory of my calculator back in the day when I was in school by simply closing a gab on the pcb with solder.

In an industry that is based on ever expanding feature sets, it doesn't make sense to advertise the lack of something like jpeg compression. Again, the main mass market doesn't even use RAW. Even professional photographers use jpeg. The target audience for a RAW only camera is too small to care about. And even for those that want a camera like that, what would be the benefits for them? There wouldn't be a significant price difference to make the camera more attractive to buy.